# responsive design screens width consideration

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend, media-queries

I just start working on a frontend side of a project and as usual I have to make it as responsive as it can be, so meanwhile dealing with @media screens I really got lost because of the variety of screens width,
the list is keep going but what I prepared my media for :

[1024, 1280,1360,1440,1600,1920,2048,2560,3840,...]

so my question for the front-end experts is  : do you follow the list up?
or there's better practice or a better way to get the job done?
and how about the gap between 2 different screens width (Ex: I noticed sometimes elements got ugly for example on 1500px screen width, *I know there might not be a screen with that size but users can reduce the size of the window so that size can occur*).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What designs have you been given for different types of device? Once you have those then at most you need breakpoints for each. You may even just have one design for all viewport aspect ratios/sizes. To get things responsive use wherever possible relative units not fixed like px.

Comment: actually I am working on a TV project containing a lot of screens, and I am using grid to arrange them perfectly and make them responsive so the number of the screens per each line be suitable, and each screen has its control panel as well, and yes thanks for reminding I am using rem & em in all my projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yout dont want to have a CSS with full of @media screens for every pixel. just use the basic pixels for mobile,portrait, landscape, Tablets, and Desktop, etc...
it dont matter if they have 1500px screen becoz when you customize your browser between 1440px and 2kpx, then the 1500 has the inscreased size of what the element has at 1440px. so dont be that specific. Try these and it should be enough.

```
<style type="text/css">
/* default styles here for older browsers. 
   I tend to go for a 600px - 960px width max but using percentages
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    /* styles for browsers larger than 960px; */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    /* styles for browsers larger than 1440px; */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
    /* for sumo sized (mac) screens */
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
}
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
   /* default iPad screens */
}
/* different techniques for iPad screening */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts only */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts only */
}
```